# comparing strings in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, search, utf-8

Is there any way in PostgreSQL to convert UTF-8 characters to "similar" ASCII characters?

String `glāžšķūņu rūķīši` would have to be converted to `glazskunu rukisi`. UTF-8 text is not in some specific language, it might be in Latvian, Russian, English, Italian or any other language.

This is needed for using in `where` clause, so it might be just "comparing strings" rather than "converting strings".

I tried using `convert`, but it does not give desired results (e.g., `select convert('Ā', 'utf8', 'sql_ascii')` gives `\304\200`, not `A`).

Database is created with:

```
ENCODING = 'UTF8'
LC_COLLATE = 'Latvian_Latvia.1257'
LC_CTYPE = 'Latvian_Latvia.1257'
```

These params may be changed, if necessary.

Comment: I think you're going to have to write your own.  Then we can all use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found different ways to do this on the [PostgreSQL Wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/).

In plperl:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unaccent_string(text) RETURNS text AS $$
my ($input_string) = @_;
$input_string =~ s/[âãäåāăą]/a;
$input_string =~ s/[ÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄ]/A;
$input_string =~ s/[èééêëēĕėęě]/e;
$input_string =~ s/[ĒĔĖĘĚ]/E;
$input_string =~ s/[ìíîïìĩīĭ]/i;
$input_string =~ s/[ÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬ]/I;
$input_string =~ s/[óôõöōŏő]/o;
$input_string =~ s/[ÒÓÔÕÖŌŎŐ]/O;
$input_string =~ s/[ùúûüũūŭů]/u;
$input_string =~ s/[ÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮ]/U;
return $input_string;
$$ LANGUAGE plperl;
```

In pure SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unaccent_string(text)
RETURNS text
IMMUTABLE
STRICT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT translate(
    $1,
    'âãäåāăąÁÂÃÄÅĀĂĄèééêëēĕėęěĒĔĖĘĚìíîïìĩīĭÌÍÎÏÌĨĪĬóôõöōŏőÒÓÔÕÖŌŎŐùúûüũūŭůÙÚÛÜŨŪŬŮ',
    'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiooooooooooooooouuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu'
);
$$;
```

And in plpython:

```
create or replace function unaccent(text) returns text language plpythonu as $$
import unicodedata
rv = plpy.execute("select setting from pg_settings where name = 'server_encoding'");
encoding = rv[0]["setting"]
s = args[0].decode(encoding)
s = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", s)
s = ''.join(c for c in s if ord(c) < 127)
return s
$$;
```

In your case, a translate() call with all the characters you can find in the [UTF-8 table](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) should be enough.

Comment: This pure SQL solution is the best I think if you need somewhat limited character set (for example only Latin based alphabets). It will be fast, is easily understandable and does not need any non-standard modules. Just get all characters from ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-2 and ISO-8859-15 - it should be enough.

Comment: For now, pure SQL function is being used. Though, it's not as good as I would like it to be... About mentioned character encodings - it is NOT enough, as it does not cover Latvian (I'm from Latvia) and probably many other languages too - at least ISO-8859-4 should be added. To make it more complete, I took all letters with diactrics from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic (just copied to notepad all the text and removed all "standard" characters by using ctrl+h) and wrote equal latin letters, then joined it with letters from examples provided by analogue.

Answer (score 2):

Use  `pg_collkey()` for ICU supported unicode compare:
 - http://www.public-software-group.org/pg_collkey
 - http://russ.garrett.co.uk/tag/postgresql/

Comment: Can't try it right now (I don't know how to compile it on Windows). And from what I read, I'm not sure if pg_collkey would work for us, because we need to use some simple patterns, e.g., string `%mazs%rukitis%` would have to match `mazs glāžšķūņu rūķītis`.