# Similar UTF-8 strings for autocomplete field

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, plpgsql, string-comparison, similarity

### Background

Users can type in a name and the system should match the text, even if the either the user input or the database field contains accented (UTF-8) characters. This is using the `pg_trgm` module.

### Problem

The code resembles the following:

```
  SELECT
    t.label
  FROM
    the_table t
  WHERE
    label % 'fil'
  ORDER BY
    similarity( t.label, 'fil' ) DESC
```

When the user types `fil`, the query matches `filbert` but not `filé powder`. (Because of the accented character?)

#### Failed Solution #1

I tried to implement an [unaccent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3051845/59087) function and rewrite the query as:

```
  SELECT
    t.label
  FROM
    the_table t
  WHERE
    unaccent( label ) % unaccent( 'fil' )
  ORDER BY
    similarity( unaccent( t.label ), unaccent( 'fil' ) ) DESC
```

This returns only `filbert`.

#### Failed Solution #2

As suggested:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unaccent_text(text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
  SELECT unaccent($1); 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
  COST 1;
```

All other indexes on the table have been dropped. Then:

```
CREATE INDEX label_unaccent_idx 
ON the_table( lower( unaccent_text( label ) ) );
```

This returns only one result:

```
  SELECT
    t.label
  FROM
    the_table t
  WHERE
    label % 'fil'
  ORDER BY
    similarity( t.label, 'fil' ) DESC
```

### Question

What is the best way to rewrite the query to ensure that both results are returned?

Thank you!

### Related

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.0#Unaccent_filtering_dictionary

http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/index-refuses-to-build-td5108810.html

Comment: Are all your searches left anchored? If so, good old `LIKE` will serve you well in combination with an index using `text_pattern_ops` (and your unaccent function). I wrote [more about that here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql/10696#10696). Also, are you aware of the [PostgreSQL unaccent module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/unaccent.html)?

Comment: Why are you using unaccent on the literal without accents, instead of the column containing the accents?  I hope you used the unaccent function in defining the index, too.  If so, it won't think it can use the index without using the same function on the search conditions.

Comment: The searches are not left anchored. I didn't know about the unaccent module. I'll look into unaccenting the index. I mistyped the `unaccent` call, the failed solution now reflects reality.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using the operator class provided by the `pg_trgm` module. Create an index like this:

```sql
CREATE INDEX label_Lower_unaccent_trgm_idx
ON test_trgm USING gist (lower(unaccent_text(label)) gist_trgm_ops);
```

Originally, I had a GIN index here, but a GiST is typically better suited for this kind of query because it can return values sorted by similarity. See:

- [Matching patterns between multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281103/postgresql-matching-patterns-between-two-columns/11282358#11282358)
- [Finding similar strings with PostgreSQL quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249635/finding-similar-strings-with-postgresql-quickly/11250001#11250001)

Your query has to match the index expression to be able to use it.

```sql
SELECT label
FROM   the_table
WHERE  lower(unaccent_text(label)) % 'fil'
ORDER  BY similarity(label, 'fil') DESC;  -- ok to use original string here
```

However, "filbert" and "filé powder" are not actually very similar to "fil" according to the `%` operator. I suspect you really want:

```sql
SELECT label
FROM   the_table
WHERE  lower(unaccent_text(label)) LIKE 'fil%'  -- !
ORDER  BY similarity(label, 'fil') DESC;  -- ok to use original string here
```

This finds all strings starting with the search string, and sorts the best matches according to the `%` operator first.

The expression can use a GIN or GiST index since PostgreSQL **9.1**! [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-FUNC-TABLE):

> Beginning in PostgreSQL 9.1, these index types also support index
> searches for `LIKE` and `ILIKE`, for example

**If** you actually meant to use the `%` operator:

Try [**adapting the threshold**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-FUNC-TABLE) for the similarity operator `%`:

```
SET pg_trgm.similarity_threshold = 0.1;  -- Postgres 9.6 or later
SELECT set_limit(0.1);  -- Postgres 9.5 or older
```

Or even lower? The default is 0.3. Just to see whether the threshold filters additional matches.

Comment: Thank you, Erwin; it may have been the `set_limit`.

Comment: @DaveJarvis: After [recent test results](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11250001/939860), I amended my answer to use a GiST index instead of GIN. May be of interest to you. (Reposted with link.)

Answer (score 4):

A solution for PostgreSQL 9.1:

```
-- Install the requisite extensions.
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;

-- Function fixes STABLE vs. IMMUTABLE problem of the unaccent function.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION unaccent_text(text)
  RETURNS text AS
$BODY$
  -- unaccent is STABLE, but indexes must use IMMUTABLE functions.
  SELECT unaccent($1); 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE
  COST 1;

-- Create an unaccented index.
CREATE INDEX the_table_label_unaccent_idx
ON the_table USING gin (lower(unaccent_text(label)) gin_trgm_ops);

-- Define the matching threshold.
SELECT set_limit(0.175);

-- Test the query (matching against the index expression).
SELECT
  label
FROM
  the_table
WHERE
  lower(unaccent_text(label)) % 'fil'
ORDER BY
  similarity(label, 'fil') DESC
```

Returns "filbert", "fish fillet", and "filé powder".

Without calling `SELECT set_limit(0.175);`, you can use the double tilde (`~~`) operator:

```
-- Test the query (matching against the index expression).
SELECT
  label
FROM
  the_table
WHERE
  lower(unaccent_text(label)) ~~ 'fil'
ORDER BY
  similarity(label, 'fil') DESC
```

Also returns "filbert", "fish fillet", and "filé powder".

Comment: +1 I like that you supply your solution in a solid format for others. Also addresses the STABLE vs. IMMUTABLE problem.