# trying to understand postgreSQL database after migrating from SQLite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I used to develop on `SQLite3` and deploy on `PostgreSQL`. However, after this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249059/generic-ruby-solution-for-sqlite3-like-or-postgresql-ilike) I realised the importance of having the same database for development and production.

After many problems, I finally managed to install the `PostgreSQL` on my Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4.   However, I am still facing some problems:

- Using `SQLite3` the databases' path is defined on the `database.yml`, which rails **automatically creates** within each new project.
- Using `PostgreSQL` the database name is defined on the `database.yml`, which rails **doesn't create** automatically.

**My question:**

> Shall I create a new database for each new project or shall I change the `database.yml` to include the same database for all projects?

I saw people saying that each user in a computer should have one database, when using `PostgreSQL`.
Well, if the best practice is to create one database for each project (which I hope so)...

> There is any way to configure rails to create the new database automatically within each new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

I have followed [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf5jPUJAeU4) tutorial and I could finally solve the problem.

I have created a new user for my `postgreSQL` called `user1` without any password, so each time I create a new project I just need to change the `database.yml` for the below:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: newproject_development
  pool: 5
  username: user1 #I am changing this line
  password:

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: newproject_test
  pool: 5
  username: user1 #I am changing this line
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: newproject_production
  pool: 5
  username: user1 #I am changing this line
  password:
```

As the the `user1` doen't have any password, now I can just create the tables using the Rails `rake`.

```
rake db:create:all
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a DB is mostly one-time operation, so it's not a big deal to create it once for a project. A casual Postgresql admin can use pgAdmin graphical tool.

Comment: so, for each new project I must create 3 databases manually? `database_development`, `database_test` and `database_production`

Comment: I thought should have an easy way, like using `rake db:create`, but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

If you use Postgresql for development, you need to create database by your self.

But you can initialize you project for Postgresql.

```
rails new my_project -d postgresql
```

Have a good day.

Benjamin.

Comment: thanks for that, but I thought there was an easier way, like using `rake db:create`...