# How to cast ID field to text in squeel query

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-1.9.3, squeel

I essentially want to [perform a LIKE query on a PostgreSQL primary id column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654657/how-do-i-perform-a-like-query-on-a-postgresql-primary-id-column) for a query generated using [Squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) and I don't think Squeel is understanding the syntax I'm giving it.  Any ideas?

##### Active Record

```
Task.where("(id::text LIKE ?)", "%1%").to_sql
=> "SELECT \"tasks\".* FROM \"tasks\"  WHERE ((id::text LIKE '%1%'))"
```

##### Squeel

```
Task.where{(id::text =~ "%#{criteria}%")}.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"tasks\".* FROM \"tasks\"  WHERE \"id\".\"text\" ILIKE '%criteria%'"
```

Comment: Wow, it has been a while since I heard about that gem.  AFAIR, that works on top of ActiveRecord, so why don't you just use the same `Task.where("(id::text LIKE ?)", "%1%")` you're giving as an example? squeel has been archived, and the last useful commit was done 8 years ago, so the chances that don't support PostgreSQL casting are high.

Comment: @AlterLagos The reason for not using ActiveRecord is because I was wanting to use other things in the squeel library and wasn't sure how to merge them either.  For example I was wanting to use the `|` operator to concatenate queries with an "or".  Though I can do this with Active Record as well.