# Sqlite3 on development and mysql2 on production

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, production-environment

I built a rails app with sqlite3 in development. Now that i want to deploy to rackspace using mysql2 i want to know what changes i need. I don't want to transfer any data from development to production environment. My database.yml file looks like this:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Can you please tell me what changes I need in this file and what else do I have to do?

Comment: suggestion by own experience: avoid using different environments for production and development... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249059/generic-ruby-solution-for-sqlite3-like-or-postgresql-ilike

Answer (score 1):

You'll want your production database to look something like this:

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: name-of-your-mysql2-database-here
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: your_password
```