# Pulling unique case-insensitive values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using jQuery autocomplete in a few areas. It makes a call to this method:

```
def index
    @schools = School.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%").limit(10)
    render json: @schools.map(&:name)
end
```

Initially I didn't handle case sensitivity well, so I have some duplicate names in differing cases (ie. "Rutgers" and "rutgers".

I'd like to change the above method to return only unique values, ignoring the case, so only one "Rutgers" result will be returned.

I'm going to clean up the DB but a quick temp fix for this would be great!

Comment: what is your DB name ?

Comment: You want case sensitive search right ?

Comment: Case insensitive. If there are two entries: "Rutgers" and "rUtGeRs", and a user searches for "RUTG", I just want to return a single result. I'm using SQLite3 in dev, postgres in production.

Comment: What DB you are using..Mysql, Oracle.. what ?

Comment: Also, note, `LIKE` queries are highly inefficient and probably not sufficient for the responsiveness you expect on an autocomplete field.

Comment: "I'm using SQLite3 in dev, postgres in production." Please stop doing that to yourself. Use the same database in dev and production, ORMs do **not** provide database portability.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on which DB you are using, but you can try doing something like this:

```
def index
  @school_names = School.order("lower(name)")
                        .where("name ilike ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
                        .distinct.limit(10).pluck("lower(name)")
  render json: @school_names.map(&:downcase)
end
```

The above will work with POSTGRESQL, for Sqlite, this will work:

```
def index
  @school_names = School.order("lower(name)")
                        .where("lower(name) LIKE lower(?)", "%#{params[:term]}%")
                        .distinct.limit(10).pluck("lower(name)")
  render json: @school_names.map(&:downcase)
end
```

Comment: The 'pluck' method returns an array, which the rest of the methods don't work on :P

Comment: Look above, I made the edit to my comment 10 minutes ago. And why can't I tell someone that their solution didn't work for me?

Comment: @opticon Because, your original question still lacks the information need to help you(If I don't care the comment). You have updated the comment after my second repetition. This answer came out from *guess*, that *Uri* mentioned. Many of us don't answer on guess, but some do although. While you don't ask question properly, don't expect others also to come correctly... That's my whole point.

Comment: @opticon - I've updated my answer(moved `pluck` to the end of the query), also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249059/generic-ruby-solution-for-sqlite3-like-or-postgresql-ilike