# Search for contact name, but case insensitive or lower case

Tags: java, android

I am building an app which looks for a contact number, according to an input. For example when the input is `james` it will find `james` in my contactsbook, (my input has to be always lower case due reasons) but when my contactsbook only contains `James` with uppercase, it won't find it.

In my code I have this:

```
String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" like'%" + name +"%'";
```

Where `name` is the input, we can also see the like operator which causes this problem I guess.

So I want to make the search case insensitive, or make all DISPLAY_NAME lowercase before searching. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
 String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME.toLowerCase()+" like'%" + name +"%'";
```

This will sort you. The [sql solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249059/generic-ruby-solution-for-sqlite3-like-or-postgresql-ilike) is not locale-sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

Call 'toLower()' on the String as in:

```
String selection = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME.toLowerCase()+" like'%" + name +"%'";
```

or

```
String selection = (ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME+" like'%" + name +"%'").toLowerCase();
```