# Converting SQL command to Active Record for LIKE Command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, sqlite

I have a sql query which I have written in the following way:

```
SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE (title LIKE '%intro%' OR isbn LIKE '%intro%' or status like '%intro%' or author like '%intro%' or description like '%intro%')
```

In my rails model I wrote the following way:

```
def self.search(query)
  where(['title LIKE ? OR isbn LIKE ? or status like ? or author like ? or description like ?', "%#{query}%", "%#{query}%","%#{query}%","%#{query}%","%#{query}%"])
end
```

This works on my sqlite3 database and returns all rows with the query "intro".

However in my postgres database it returns only one row. Could some one suggest me a way.

Contents of my table:

```
id  isbn    title   description author  status
2   15  Introduction to english Introduction to english veena kapoor    available
3   16  Introduction to hindi   Introduction to hindi   rastogi vinayak available
4   17  Introduction to sanskrit    Introduction to sanskrit    edward solomon  available
```

Comment: Does the original SQL query return the result you expect in the Postgres database? When you look at the Rails log, what SQL is your Rails method generating?

Comment: @Jordan It does not work in Postgres, but works in sqlite

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the data from the Postgres database that you expect to be returned but isn't?

Comment: @huanson Could you suggest a way to make this work in both sqlite & postgres ?

Comment: @Jordan All the columns are mentioned in my query itself

Comment: Not the column names. The actual data in the database rows. We can't help you figure out why a query didn't select the rows if we don't know what's in the rows.

Comment: PS: You could make that a lot nicer with named placeholders: `where('title ilike :pat or isbn ilike :pat ...', :pat => "%#{query}%")`.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for the suggestion! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `WHERE title LIKE '%intro%'` (for example) won't match the value `'Introduction to english'` because `LIKE` is case-sensitive in Postgres. You must `ILIKE` to do a case-insensitive match.

This may be a problem, since `ILIKE` doesn't work in SQLite. Take a look at this question for some potential solutions: [Generic Ruby solution for SQLite3 "LIKE" or PostgreSQL "ILIKE"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249059/generic-ruby-solution-for-sqlite3-like-or-postgresql-ilike) The best solution (as proffered by the top-rated answer there) is to use the same database (Postgres) in both development and production.