# JSON data showing in development properly but in production does not showing properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sqlite

This is my routes.rb

```
namespace :api do
    get 'suggestions/jobs', to: "suggestions#jobs"
end
```

My controller

```
class Api::SuggestionsController < ApplicationController
    def jobs
        @jobs = Job.job_title_search(params[:q])   #.select(:title, :label).distinct
        if @jobs.present?
            render json: @jobs, status: :ok
        else
            render json: "Not Found", status: :ok
        end
    end
end
```

and model

```
def self.job_title_search(q)
    where('title LIKE ?', "%#{q}%").select(:title, :label).distinct
end
```

in the development environment like `localhost:3000/api/suggestions/jobs?q=dev` the data sample is

```
[
    {"id":null,"title":"React Native Developer","label":"Top label job"},
    {"id":null,"title":"Android Developer","label":"Top label job"},
    {"id":null,"title":"Business Development Representative","label":"Mid label job"},
    {"id":null,"title":"Node.js Developer","label":"Top label job"}
]
```

that means it's working, but while I pushed into the Heroku then like `example.herokuapp.com/api/suggestions/jobs?q=dev` it's showing

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

I know there is "Not Found" like the code is

```
render json: "Not Found", status: :ok
```

My question is why same code is not working on Heroku? and What can I do for this?

the database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: my_project_production
  username: my_project
  password: <%= ENV['MY_PROJECT_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Any help appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the `database.yml` for checking the database adapter, I think it's causing for database adapter, the `like` does not work in `PostgreSQL` OTOH, `ilike` does not work in `SQLite`,  if you use `SQLite` for development & `PostgreSQL` for production,

Comment: @fool-dev I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look the `LIKE` keyword in SQL, if you use `SQLite` database for `development` and `PostgreSQL` database for `production` then maybe it's happened, the `like` is working on the development environment and production environment will be `ilike` the `like` does not work, OTOH, `ilike` does not work in `SQLite`.

If so then the solution is:

**Solution 1** You can change the development database to `PostgreSQL`, if you have worry about changing the database then follow the below

**Solution 2** You can use `lower(attr)` like

```
def self.job_title_search(q)
    where('lower(title) LIKE lower(?)', "%#{q}%").select(:title, :label).distinct
end
```

You can see the [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278943/4172515) for this.

Hope will help.

Answer (score 6):

The `if` branch of your code is fine, and since `dev` contains records, it’s being rendered without any glitch.

In `prod`, OTOH, there are no records and the `else` branch, which is not quite correct, is tried to be rendered. And it fails, giving you the error.

Do supply a hash there instead:

```
else
  render json: {error: "Not Found"}, status: :ok
end
```

Comment: "OTOH" = "**O**bfuscated **T**ext **O**nly **H**inders" (I believe) :)

Comment: @engineersmnky **O**n **T**he **O**ther **H**and, but I like your interpretation more.

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks for the answer, my question is the search query is not working, it's going to else block

Comment: @jesica do you have the data in production? It looks like you haven’t that’s why it’s going to `else` block.

Comment: Yes I have lots of data if I use like `Job.all` then it will return the data

Comment: Then check `params[:q]`—it looks like the scope returns an empty set.

Comment: @mudasobwa +1 for you but the solution from the `fool-dev` answer, you answer's helped me a lot, Thanks