# Matching patterns between multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching

I have two columns say `Main` and `Sub`. (they can be of same table or not).

`Main` is varchar of length 20 and `Sub` is varchar of length 8.
`Sub` is **always** subset of `Main` and it is last 8 characters of `Main`.

I could successfully design a query to match pattern using `substr("Main",13,8)`

Query:

```
select * from "MainTable"
 where substr("MainColumn",13,8) LIKE (
   select "SubColumn" From "SubTable" Where "SubId"=1043);
```

but I want to use Like, % , _ etc in my query so that I can loosely match the pattern (that is not all 8 characters).

Question is how can i do that.?!

I know that the query below is **COMPLETELY WRONG** but I want to achieve something like this,

```
Select * from "MainTable"
 Where "MainColumn" Like '%' Select "SubColumn" From "SubTable" Where "SubId"=2'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers so far fail to address your question:

> but I want use Like, % , _ etc in my query so that I can loosely match
>   the pattern (that is not all 8 characters).

It makes hardly any difference whether you use `LIKE` or `=` as long as you match the whole string (and there are no wildcard character *in* your string). To make the search fuzzy, you need to *replace* part of the pattern, not just add to it.

For instance, to match on the last 7 (instead of 8) characters of `subcolumn`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   maintable m
WHERE  left(maincolumn, 8) LIKE 
       ( '%' || left((SELECT subcolumn FROM subtable WHERE subid = 2), 7));
```

I use the simpler `left()` (introduced with Postgres 9.1).
You `could` simplify this to:

```
SELECT *
FROM   maintable m
WHERE  left(maincolumn, 7) =
       (SELECT left(subcolumn,7) FROM subtable WHERE subid = 2);
```

But you wouldn't if you use the special index I mention further down, because expressions in functional indexes have to matched precisely to be of use.

You may be interested in the extension [`pg_tgrm`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html).

In PostgreSQL 9.1 run once per database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_tgrm;
```

Two reasons:

- It supplies the [**similarity operator `%`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html#PGTRGM-OP-TABLE). With it you can build a smart similarity search:

  ```
  --SELECT show_limit();
  SELECT set_limit(0.5); -- adjust similarity limit for % operator

  SELECT *
  FROM maintable m
  WHERE left(maincolumn, 8) %
        (SELECT subcolumn FROM subtable WHERE subid = 2);
  ```
- It supplies [**index support**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html#AEN137099) for both `LIKE` and `%`

  If read performance is more important than write performance, I suggest you create a [functional](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) GIN or GiST index like this:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX maintable_maincol_tgrm_idx ON maintable
  USING gist (left(maincolumn, 8) gist_trgm_ops);
  ```

  This index supports either query. Be aware that it comes with some cost for write operations.
  [A quick benchmark for a similar case in this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11250001/939860).

Comment: If you use a GiST index instead of GIN, a similarity search ordered by similarity `DESC` and with a `LIMIT` will use KNN searching of the index -- the index will actually return rows in order of "best match". This can be much faster than alternatives.  The value used in `set_limit()` can have a major impact on the performance of KNN searches, so play with that to make sure you're not including matches which are too "loose" to really be of any interest. (KNN is a notation meaning that you want "k" nearest neighbors, where "k" is a number you provide.)

Comment: @indyaah: I added a link to a related answer that illustrates the performance of GiST and GIN indexes - just like Kevin describes it. Also amended the example here to display a GiST index, which is the better pick.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SELECT t1.* from "Main Table" AS t1, "SubTable" AS t2
 WHERE t2.SubId=1043
   AND substr(t1.MainColumn, 13, 8) LIKE "%" || CAST(t2.SubColumn as text);
```

Comment: actually i wanted to avoid using substr().

Answer (score 2):

Argument to a [`LIKE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) is an ordinary string, so all string manipulations are valid here.
In your case you need to concatenate wildchars with the target substring, like @bksi suggests:

```
... LIKE '%'||CAST("SubColumn" AS test) ...
```

Note, though, that such patterns (the ones starting with a `%` wildcard) are badly performing ones. Take a look at [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations).

I would recommend:

- sticking with the current `substr("MainColumn", 13, 8)` approach;
- avoid `LIKE` and use equality comparison (`=`) instead (although they're equal if `LIKE` pattern contains no wildcards, it is easier to read the query);
- build an [expression index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createindex.html) on the "MainTable" the following way:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX i_maincolumn ON "MainTable" (substr("MainColumn", 13, 8));
  ```

This combination will perform better in my view.

And use lowercase names for the tables/columns, so that you can avoid doublequoting them.