# LOWER LIKE vs iLIKE

Tags: performance, postgresql, pattern-matching, database-performance

How does the performance of the following two query components compare?

**LOWER LIKE**

```
... LOWER(description) LIKE '%abcde%' ...
```

**iLIKE**

```
... description iLIKE '%abcde%' ...
```

Comment: What is your goal? Do you have a slow SQL command that you want to speed it up or is it just a general question on PostgreSQL?

Comment: Stack Overflow hasn't (yet?) #hashtags (unless you are asking a C or C++ question).

Comment: @MartinStrejc my goal is just a general question on PostgreSQL. Presented with the choice of these two out-of-the-box solutions, I wanted to know which to use.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

The answer depends on many factors like Postgres version, encoding and locale - [`LC_COLLATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html) in particular.

The bare expression `lower(description) LIKE '%abc%'` is typically a bit faster than `description ILIKE '%abc%'`, and either is a bit faster than the equivalent regular expression: `description ~* 'abc'`. This matters for sequential scans where the expression has to be evaluated for every tested row.

**But** for big tables like you demonstrate in your answer one would certainly use an index. For arbitrary patterns (not only left-anchored) I suggest a trigram index using the additional module [`pg_trgm`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html). Then we talk about milliseconds instead of seconds and the difference between the above expressions is nullified.

GIN and GiST indexes (using the `gin_trgm_ops` or `gist_trgm_ops` operator classes) support `LIKE` (`~~`),  `ILIKE` (`~~*`), `~`, `~*` (and some more variants) alike. With a trigram GIN index on `description` (typically bigger than GiST, but faster for reads), your query would use `description ILIKE 'case_insensitive_pattern'`.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)
- [Similar UTF-8 strings for autocomplete field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237366/similar-utf-8-strings-for-autocomplete-field/10238113#10238113)

Basics for pattern matching in Postgres:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)

When working with said trigram index it's *typically* more practical to work with:

```
description ILIKE '%abc%'
```

Or with the case-insensitive regexp operator (without `%` wildcards):

```
description ~* 'abc'
```

An index on `(description)` does not support queries on `lower(description)` like:

```
lower(description) LIKE '%abc%'
```

And vice versa.

With predicates on `lower(description)` *exclusively*, the expression index is the slightly better option.

In all other cases, an index on `(description)` is preferable as it supports *both* case-sensitive and -insensitive predicates.

Comment: I will consider your suggestion, though I just wanted to clarify that my intent was to compare these two out-of-the-box solutions. I re-ran my tests and have updated my answer to reflect mixed-case data. I also added details about my database. It turns out that `LOWER` `LIKE` is still about `17%` faster than `iLIKE` (a drop from `25%`).

Comment: Worth noting that the reported 17% were for sequential scans *without* index. I got 2% for a similar test, [see other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20336665/lower-like-vs-ilike/20337500#comment30360203_20336666). And neither applies if a trigram index is added to the setup - which nullifies the difference.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. Would you think it fair to add this comment to your answer? - I think that the selected answer should conclude that `LOWER LIKE` is faster (unless a trigram index is added, in which case, as you said, there is no difference)... but the point is that `LOWER LIKE` is what folks should use, not `iLIKE`, which will either be equivalent or slower.

Comment: @user664833: Well, no, not generally. I clarified above.

Comment: Doesn't the use of like vs ilike depend of how you stored your data? If you have 'Joe' in the DB, then you need to lower twice: `lower(input) LIKE lower('%Joe%'). That's why ILIKE was created I suppose...

Answer (score 39):

According to my tests (*ten* of each query), `LOWER` `LIKE` is about `17%` faster than `iLIKE`.

**Explanation**

I created a million rows contain some random mixed text data:

```
require 'securerandom'
inserts = []
1000000.times do |i|
        inserts << "(1, 'fake', '#{SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(64)}')"
end
sql = "insert into books (user_id, title, description) values #{inserts.join(', ')}"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Verify the number of rows:

```
my_test_db=# select count(id) from books ;
  count  
---------
 1000009
```

(Yes, I have nine extra rows from other tests - not a problem.)

Example query and results:

```
my_test_db=# SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."published" = 'f'
my_test_db=# and (LOWER(description) LIKE '%abcde%') ;
   id    | user_id | title |                                      description                                       | published 
---------+---------+-------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------
 1232322 |       1 | fake  | 5WRGr7oCKABcdehqPKsUqV8ji61rsNGS1TX6pW5LJKrspOI_ttLNbaSyRz1BwTGQxp3OaxW7Xl6fzVpCu9y3fA | f
 1487103 |       1 | fake  | J6q0VkZ8-UlxIMZ_MFU_wsz_8MP3ZBQvkUo8-2INiDIp7yCZYoXqRyp1Lg7JyOwfsIVdpPIKNt1uLeaBCdelPQ | f
 1817819 |       1 | fake  | YubxlSkJOvmQo1hkk5pA1q2mMK6T7cOdcU3ADUKZO8s3otEAbCdEcmm72IOxiBdaXSrw20Nq2Lb383lq230wYg | f
```

**Results for LOWER LIKE**

```
my_test_db=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."published" = 'f' and (LOWER(description) LIKE '%abcde%') ;
                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on books  (cost=0.00..32420.14 rows=1600 width=117) (actual time=938.627..4114.038 rows=3 loops=1)
   Filter: ((NOT published) AND (lower(description) ~~ '%abcde%'::text))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1000006
 Total runtime: 4114.098 ms
```

**Results for iLIKE**

```
my_test_db=# EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT "books".* FROM "books" WHERE "books"."published" = 'f' and (description iLIKE '%abcde%') ;
                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                   
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on books  (cost=0.00..29920.11 rows=100 width=117) (actual time=1147.612..4986.771 rows=3 loops=1)
   Filter: ((NOT published) AND (description ~~* '%abcde%'::text))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 1000006
 Total runtime: 4986.831 ms
```

**Database info disclosure**

Postgres version:

```
my_test_db=# select version();
                                                                                 version
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.2.4 on x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0, compiled by i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00), 64-bit
```

Collation setting:

```
my_test_db=# select datcollate from pg_database where datname = 'my_test_db';
 datcollate  
-------------
 en_CA.UTF-8
```

Table definition:

```
my_test_db=# \d books 
                                      Table "public.books"
   Column    |            Type             |                       Modifiers
-------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                     | not null default nextval('books_id_seq'::regclass)
 user_id     | integer                     | not null
 title       | character varying(255)      | not null
 description | text                        | not null default ''::text
 published   | boolean                     | not null default false
Indexes:
    "books_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
```

Comment: Your test case is one-sided, there are only upper-case letters in the data. Also, in a real-life application, you would be operating with indices, which changes the whole assessment. And *essential* details are undisclosed: Postgres version, your collation setting, your exact table definition.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I re-ran my tests and have updated my answer to reflect mixed-case data. I also added details about my database. `LOWER` `LIKE` is still about `17%` faster than `iLIKE` (a drop from `25%`).

Comment: +1 Much better now. I wouldn't say "x is 17% faster than y", though,  since this is only true for your particular test case. The length of the string is also relevant, btw.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter - I realize that precise percentage results will vary but I also thought that just saying "x is faster than y" was too open ended. I think that with your comment folks who are sufficiently curious will get a more complete picture. By the way, are you aware of a condition of string length, collation setting, or something else, which would consistently result in `iLIKE` out performing `LOWER` `LIKE`?

Comment: No. Not sure, though. I often see much closer results. Ran a quick test on a real-life table in Postgres 9.1 with 1.05M rows and real-life "descriptions", COLLATON de_AT.UTF-8, OS Debian Linux. LOWER / LIKE was ~ 2% faster.

Comment: Curious what happens if you index description field. Can ILIKE take the same advantage of the index as LIKE? Normally I would not be searching a column without an index.

Comment: @Speedy99: I addressed that in an update to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337500/939860).

Answer (score 3):

In my rails Project. `ILIKE` is almost 10x faster then `LOWER LIKE`, I add a `GIN` index on `entities.name` column

```
> Entity.where("LOWER(name) LIKE ?", name.strip.downcase).limit(1).first
Entity Load (2443.9ms)  SELECT  "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE (lower(name) like 'baidu') ORDER BY "entities"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

```
> Entity.where("name ILIKE ?", name.strip).limit(1).first
Entity Load (285.0ms)  SELECT  "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE (name ilike 'Baidu') ORDER BY "entities"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

```
# explain analyze SELECT  "entities".* FROM "entities" WHERE (name ilike 'Baidu') ORDER BY "entities"."id" ASC LIMIT 1;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=3186.03..3186.04 rows=1 width=1588) (actual time=7.812..7.812 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=3186.03..3187.07 rows=414 width=1588) (actual time=7.811..7.811 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: id
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 26kB
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on entities  (cost=1543.21..3183.96 rows=414 width=1588) (actual time=7.797..7.805 rows=1 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((name)::text ~~* 'Baidu'::text)
               Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 6
               Heap Blocks: exact=7
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_entities_on_name  (cost=0.00..1543.11 rows=414 width=0) (actual time=7.787..7.787 rows=7 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((name)::text ~~* 'Baidu'::text)
 Planning Time: 6.375 ms
 Execution Time: 7.874 ms
(12 rows)
```

GIN index is really helpful to improve `ILIKE` performance

Comment: An index on `name` does not support queries on `lower(name)`. I mentioned that in my answer. That's most probably the reason for the 10x performance difference. (You'll see sequential scans instead of (bitmap) index scans.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Yes, thank you, I just get this in my project, so I put it here to show how index change the performance rule. :)