# Postgresql is not using indexes if I use search text with 5 characters. With 6 it works. Why?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, indexing, postgresql-13

I'm using Postgresql 13.

With this query PostgreSQL is using the indexes:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    "players"
WHERE team_id = 3
    AND (
    code ILIKE 'lushij'
    OR
    REPLACE(lastname||firstname,' ','') ILIKE '%lushij%'
    OR REPLACE(firstname||lastname,' ','') ILIKE '%lushij%'
    OR personal_info->>'houses' ILIKE '%lushij%'
    )
LIMIT 15
```

```
Limit  (cost=333.01..385.77 rows=15 width=360)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on players  (cost=333.01..4061.29 rows=1060 width=360)
        Recheck Cond: ((code ~~* 'lushij'::text) OR (replace((lastname || firstname), ' '::text, ''::text) ~~* '%lushij%'::text) OR (replace((firstname || lastname), ' '::text, ''::text) ~~* '%lushij%'::text) OR ((personal_info ->> 'houses'::text) ~~* '%lushij%'::text))
        Filter: (team_id = 3)
        ->  BitmapOr  (cost=333.01..333.01 rows=1060 width=0)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on players_code_trgm  (cost=0.00..116.75 rows=100 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (code ~~* 'lushij'::text)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on players_replace_last_first_name_trgm  (cost=0.00..66.40 rows=320 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (replace((lastname || firstname), ' '::text, ''::text) ~~* '%lushij%'::text)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on players_replace_first_last_name_trgm  (cost=0.00..66.40 rows=320 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (replace((firstname || lastname), ' '::text, ''::text) ~~* '%lushij%'::text)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on players_personal_info_houses_trgm_idx  (cost=0.00..82.40 rows=320 width=0)
                    Index Cond: ((personal_info ->> 'houses'::text) ~~* '%lushij%'::text)
```

With the same query but with search text with one character less (from `lushij` to `lushi`) **the indexes are NOT used**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    "players"
WHERE team_id = 3
    AND (
    code ILIKE 'lushi'
    OR
    REPLACE(lastname||firstname,' ','') ILIKE '%lushi%'
    OR REPLACE(firstname||lastname,' ','') ILIKE '%lushi%'
    OR personal_info->>'houses' ILIKE '%lushi%'
    )
LIMIT 15
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.00..235.65 rows=15 width=360)
  ->  Seq Scan on players  (cost=0.00..76853.53 rows=4892 width=360)
        Filter: ((team_id = 3) AND ((code ~~* 'lushi'::text) OR (replace((lastname || firstname), ' '::text, ''::text) ~~* '%lushi%'::text) OR (replace((firstname || lastname), ' '::text, ''::text) ~~* '%lushi%'::text) OR ((personal_info ->> 'houses'::text) ~~* '%lushi%'::text)))
```

**Why?**

**UPDATE**:

If i comment `LIMIT 15` line the indexes are used.

---

Here the structures:

Players table structure

```sql
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for players
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "public"."players";
CREATE TABLE "public"."players" (
  "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('players_id_seq'::regclass),
  "created_at" timestamptz(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  "updated_at" timestamptz(6),
  "team_id" int8 NOT NULL,
  "firstname" text COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "lastname" text COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "code" text COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default",
  "personal_info" jsonb
)
;

-- ----------------------------
-- Indexes structure for table players
-- ----------------------------
CREATE INDEX "players_personal_info_houses_trgm_idx" ON "public"."players" USING gin (
  (personal_info ->> 'houses'::text) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" "public"."gin_trgm_ops"
);
CREATE INDEX "players_code_trgm" ON "public"."players" USING gin (
  "code" COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" "public"."gin_trgm_ops"
);
CREATE INDEX "players_lower_code" ON "public"."players" USING btree (
  lower(code) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" "pg_catalog"."text_ops" ASC NULLS LAST
);
CREATE INDEX "players_replace_first_last_name_trgm" ON "public"."players" USING gin (
  replace(firstname || lastname, ' '::text, ''::text) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" "public"."gin_trgm_ops"
);
CREATE INDEX "players_replace_last_first_name_trgm" ON "public"."players" USING gin (
  replace(lastname || firstname, ' '::text, ''::text) COLLATE "pg_catalog"."default" "public"."gin_trgm_ops"
);

-- ----------------------------
-- Primary Key structure for table players
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "public"."players" ADD CONSTRAINT "players_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id");

-- ----------------------------
-- Foreign Keys structure for table players
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "public"."players" ADD CONSTRAINT "players_team_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("team_id") REFERENCES "public"."teams" ("id") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Comment: suggested reading: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20337500/2067753 note you are using  functions and double-ended LIKE expressions plus case insensitivity - none of which are great for index use

Comment: Ok, I read that topic. But why? What does this have to do with my question?

Answer (score 1):

OK.. this is based on my knowledge of SQL Server and SQL in general, but it probably applies here too.

To start with... because you're doing a `SELECT *`, it will need to go to the clustered index at some point.

The use of the non-clustered index (if it's used) is to identify the relevant rows, and then it goes and picks out those rows 1-by-1 (a *nested loop join*, or sometimes referred to as index seek/scan + key lookup).

If there are too many rows, this is actually inefficient - you end up doing more reads/etc than simply just reading the entire table.

Reducing the length of the LIKE filter increases the cardinality estimate e.g., increases the amount of rows the filter is expected to match in the query planner/optimiser.

I'm guessing the SQL engine takes a guess (including statistics on the index/data) and determines that it's probably more efficient to simply read ALL the data from the clustered index, vs determining the rows and reading them 1-by-1.

---

Update after OP update re removing limit.

Well... once again, it depends on how many rows it estimates exist based on the filter.

Imagine if you were doing ILIKE '%e%' in the original query. Every second row may match this. As you don't have a sort, it just needs to read (say) the first 30 rows of the clustered index and it will get your answer. Once again, the query planner/optimiser may come to the conclusion that this would be the most efficient way to get these.

However, without the limit, it will need to read all rows to get all results.

- For %e% it may be more efficient to just do a full clustered index scan, as it expects many rows to match
- For more complicated/selective ones filtering, searching the index first (then seeking straight to the data in the clustered index) is often more efficient

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated the question. If I remove the LIMIT the indexes are used! Why?

Comment: Good question - I've modified my answer to reflect these.

Comment: Wow. Your answer is good. But my question is: I need to use this query for autocomplete text input. As you can imagine I have many small words, from 3 to 5 characters. How to do? With no indexes the query is doing it's job in 5 seconds! Crazy!

Comment: I don't know the comprehensive answer (e.g., Postgres text filtering) but I suggest 1) Instead of `SELECT *`, only select the field(s) you absolutely need. 2) If possible, include those field(s) in the index so it doesn't need to go to clustered index. 3) Simplify the ILIKE clauses (particularly try to make them SARGable).

Comment: Thanks. 1) I tried with `SELECT id, created_at, ...` and so on. It's the same. 2) An example? Each column in the index? 3) What do you mean? What it means `SARGable`?

Comment: If I use a query with many `UNION` it works with no problem with `LIMIT` and all.

Comment: A [multicolumn index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html) that includes all fields that are in the SELECT is called a [covering index](https://dbadiaries.com/sql-server-covering-index-and-key-lookup#:~:text=A%20covering%20index%20is%20a,it%20is%20a%20faster%20operation.). Because all the data is in the index, it never needs to go back to the clustered index. This is why you should limit the number of columns in the SELECT -  you can use a smaller covering index. (Note that the bigger the index, the more it needs to read).

Comment: [SARGable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), in easy terms, means the query can seek straight to the relevant spot in the index (remember, the index is sorted). ILIKE 'Smith%' is SARGable because it can seek straight to the 'Smith' point. ILIKE '%Smith%' isn't - the whole column needs to be read (e.g., both ASmith, ZSmith will match).

Comment: Too much guesswork, and there is no clustered index.

Comment: Good point re clustered index @Laurenz. It does seem to be a heap. However, the logic doesn't change much a heaps - it just means that whenever I was referring to the clustered index scan, it should instead refer to a table scan (and when referencing the clustered index, it instead references the internal row identifier e.g., rowid, ct_id, etc). And the suggested fixes (e.g., covering index) still apply.

Answer (score 1):

The shorter the string, the less selective your condition gets. Based on its estimates, PostgreSQL thinks that with the short string, enough rows match the condition that it is cheaper to just sequentially fetch rows and discard the ones that don't match until it has found 15 matching rows.

The many `OR` conditions may well make the optimizer underestimate the selectivity, because the conditions are considered uncorrelated, which may not be the case.

Comment: Wow. Your answer is good. But my question is: I need to use this query for autocomplete text input. As you can imagine I have many small words, from 3 to 5 characters. How to do? With no indexes the query is doing it's job in 5 seconds! Crazy!

Comment: Does the query with the short query string perform well if you (temporarily) `SET enable_seqscan = off;`?