# Ruby how to make search filters case insensitive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building an app that has search fields how can I make search filters in my app case insensitive. Can I accomplish this in the following block of code:

```
<div class="filter">
  <%= form_tag posts_path, method: :get do %>
  <%= label_tag :bedrooms %>
  <%= text_field_tag :bedrooms, params[:bedrooms] %>

  <%= label_tag :bathrooms %>
  <%= text_field_tag :bathrooms, params[:bathrooms] %>

  <%= label_tag :neighborhood %>
  <%= text_field_tag :neighborhood, params[:neighborhood] %>

  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is relevant code from controller

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
   def home
   end  

 def index
   @posts = Post.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
   @posts = @posts.where(bedrooms: params["bedrooms"])if
   params["bedrooms"].present?
   @posts = @posts.where(bathrooms: params["bathrooms"])if
   params["bathrooms"].present?
   @posts = @posts.where(neighborhood: params["neighborhood"])if
   params["neighborhood"].present?
 end
```

Comment: This is not the relevant code. The relevant code is where you do the filtering itself, in a controller or model, comparing your filter params to the attributes of the objects in your model collections, or using them in database queries.

Comment: Thanks to all for help as you can see I am a new to all this. I do understand downcase a little but not sure how to use in this context. it's only the neighborhood field I have trouble with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
posts = Post.find(:conditions => ["lower(bedroom) = ?", params[:bedrooms].downcase])
```

you can use `lower` and `downcase` to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: This writeup is based on the accepted answer to the question here.

If you are just coming in to the provided answers, here is a better explanation for using the `lower` function:

**First of all, note**: You could run into into incompatibilities - or worse: not realize some until damage is done, if you are using different Database for Development and different Database for Deployment. It's a bad idea™. Use the same RDBMS for development and production and save yourself the pointless trouble.

---

The `lower()` function works well both in SQlite and PostgreSQL and faster with its response.

- In standard SQLite `lower(X)` only folds ASCII letters. For more, I quote the chapter [Core Functions in the SQLite manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html):

  > The lower(X) function returns a copy of string X with all
  >   ASCII characters converted to lower case. The default built-in lower()
  >   function works for ASCII characters only. To do case conversions on
  >   non-ASCII characters, **load the ICU extension**.

  Better Emphasis here about PostgreSQL is that:
- [PostgreSQL `lower(X)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) works with UTF-8 out of the box.

---

As a welcome side effect, you can **speed** up that query in PostgreSQL with an [index on the expression](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-expressional.html) `lower(style)`, which will be **faster** than using `ILIKE` and a basic index on `style`.

Also, since PostgreSQL 9.1 you can use a GIN or GIST index with the [**`pg_trgm`** extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/pgtrgm.html) to speed up *any* `LIKE` and `ILIKE` query - trigrams are case-insensitive. Detailed instructions and links in this related answer:

- [Similar UTF-8 strings for autocomplete field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237366/similar-utf-8-strings-for-autocomplete-field/10238113#10238113)

This writeup is adapted from answers in Stackoverflow and basically by **Erwin Brandstetter**

Answer (score -1):

you can use **ilike** in database Query.

```
Post.where("bedrooms ilike \"#{params[:bedrooms]}\" and bathrooms ilike \"#{params[:bathrooms]}\" and neighborhood ilike \"#{params[:neighborhood]}\"")
```