# Django: filter query using database function

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a `unnaccent_string` function in my postgres database like described here:
[comparing strings in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051762/comparing-strings-in-postgresql)

so that

`unnaccent_string(órfão) == 'orfao'`

Is it possible to build a Django QuerySet that would let me do something like `Person.objects.filter(unnaccent_string(name)__icontains='joao')` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use queryset's [`extra()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#extra) method:

```
Person.objects.extra(where=['unnaccent_string(name) LIKE %s'),
                     params=['%joao%'])
```

Comment: Hey Tony! I'd sugestão you to wrap this option in a custon manager in order to avoid passing só many arguments every time.